# Visual Studio: Prevent copy file on build ignoring hierarchy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

My project has the following structure:

```
My project
+-bin
+-lib
| +-dependency.dll
+-src
| +-Program.cs
+-My Project.csproj
```

The compilation output is placed in the `bin` folder. I've set the action property for `dependency.dll` to *None/Copy if newer*. The problem is that a `lib` subfolder is created in the `bin` directory when I'd like all the files to be in `bin` (no subfolder).

A solution is to put `dependency.dll` in the project root folder, but I find that kind of messy and I'd rather keep my project folder clean.

How can I force Visual to copy my DLL in the folder I want?

Comment: Have you considered using a PostBuild command?

Comment: Yeah, but it gets kind of complicated when project are referencing other projects (while it's done automatically with the action property).

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand correctly your situation. Who creates the lib folder? The dependency.dll is part of your source code and built together all the rest of your project?

Comment: I create the lib folder to keep my project organized. The dependency.dll is an external (unmanaged, FWIW) library.

Answer (score 1):

Add an AfterBuild target to your .csproj to copy the file.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <Copy SourceFiles="lib/dependency.dll"  DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: The file are copied in the correct directory, _but_ 1. On project cleanup the DLLs are not deleted, 2. if another project references this one, the DLLs are not copied, and 3. it impossible to use links to files with this method.